How to get the first value greater than x in a range with segment tree
I am trying to use a segment tree to handle queries (in O(log N) per query) of the form: find the first value > x in a particular range [ql, qr] (of an array of size N).
I've been using the recursive method to create the segment tree and to update it, but I wasn't able to retrieve the index of the first value > x in my range.
Here is my implementation that doesn't currently work:
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> seg;
vector<int> torre;
int sizeN;

//recursive build of the segtree
long long int build(int i, int l, int r, vector<int> &torri) {

    if(r-l==1) return seg[i] = torri[l]; //base case

    int mid = (l+r)/2; //split in half
    seg[i] = max(build(2*i, l, mid, torri), build((2*i)+1, mid, r, torri));

    //return the value of the segment
    return seg[i];
}

//recursive update of the segtree
void update(int i, int l, int r, int pos, long long int val) {

    if(r-l==1) { seg[i] = val; return; } //base case

    int mid = (l+r)/2; //find the middle
    if(pos<mid) update(2*i, l, mid, pos, val); //left half
    else update(2*i+1, mid, r, pos, val); //right half

    seg[i] = max(seg[2*i],seg[2*i+1]); //update with the max
}

int query_destra (int i, int l, int r, int ql, int qr, int x) {

    //base case
    if (ql >= r or qr <= l) return -1;//no intersection

    if (l >= ql and r <= qr) { //included
        if(seg[i] <= x) return -1; //if ... the node is not interesting

        //return i; <----------- IM MISSING SOMETHING HERE TO MAKE IT RETURN I CORRECTLY
    }

    int mid = (l+r)/2; //find the center

    //prioritizes the first value, if its not interesting, go to the second
    int ans = query_destra(2*i, l, mid, ql, qr, x);
    if(ans != -1) return ans;
    return query_destra(2*i+1, mid, r, ql, qr, x);
}

pair<int, int> chiedi(int x) {
    return make_pair(0 /*query_sinistra(1,0,sizeN, 0, x, torre[x])*/,query_destra(1, 0, sizeN, x, sizeN, torre[x]));
}

void cambia(int x, int h) {
    update(1, 0, sizeN, x, h);
}

void inizializza(int N, vector<int> H) {
    sizeN = H.size();
    torre.resize(sizeN);
    seg.resize(sizeN*4);
    for(int i=0; i<sizeN; i++) torre[i] = H[i];
    build(1,0,N,H);
}

int main() {
    vector vec{6, 4, 2, 0, 8, 4};
    inizializza(vec.size(), vec);
    cout << query_destra(1, 0, sizeN, 1, 5, 4) << '\n'; 
    // should produce 4, the index of the first value larger than 4 in the subarray from index 1 to 5 (exclusive), but gives -1
}


I've been able to retrieve the highest in the range, but not the first, so I tried a different approach: I tried simply putting "return i" inside the included cases but from the results it gave me it was VERY wrong, and not putting somewhere "return i" simply makes it return -1 each time.
After failing on my own, I tried following what other people did, but not only I wasn't able to understand most of the code they used, but it also didn't work for what I needed to do.
An example of how the result should be, with a starting array of [6, 4, 2, 0, 8, 4], with x = 4 and my range going from position 1 to position 5, my program should be able to return 4 (the position of the 8, the first number higher than the starting one).
I have to do this thing for a number in the array both forwards and backwards.
I'm using C++17.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

"all of my code" - Is rarely necessary. Please provide a [mre] where you have done the heavy lifting of excluding irrelevant parts from the stuff we, trying to help you, have to parse.

I've simplified your example to more clearly demonstrate the issue.

int mid = (l+r)/2; //find the middle -- Possible overflow if l + r exceeds the maximum value of an int.  Use std::midpoint instead.

@PaulMcKenzie Forgot to mention this in the main post, I'm using C++17 and that function was made for C++20 or higher

Your solution is almost correct; you are just missing the point at which you should return the actual index. When you have narrowed your search to a leaf node while descending the tree, you can directly return the left index.
Replace these lines
if (l >= ql and r <= qr) {
    if(seg[i] <= x) return -1;

    //return i;
}

with
if (seg[i] <= x) return -1;
if (r == l + 1) return l;


I don't think I understand this solution.
I tried putting your solution in my code, and it finds a seemingly random number with various examples.
I've tried this example: v[1, 3, 6, 8, 8, 9, 10] and x=1, so now the program should find the first element on the right higher than torre[1] = 3, but for some reason it returns 5 (9).
If instead of the other vector, the vector is v[1, 7, 6, 8, 8, 9, 10] and x=1, it should return 3 (the position of the first 8) but instead it returns 5 again (the position of 9).

@Tizio I forgot that you were using an exclusive right bound for your nodes. Change the line to if (r == l + 1) return l;
